# Solr indexing error while posting file

Tags: csv, solr

I am trying to post a csv file for indexing.Here is the file format:

```
        product/productId,product/title,product/price,review/userId,review/profileName,review/helpfulness,review/score,review/time,review/summary,review/text
    B00002066I,ah,15.99,unknown,unknown,3/4,5.0,939772800,Inspiring,"I hope a lot of people hear this cd. We need more strong and positive vibes like this. Great vocals, fresh tunes, cross-cultural happiness. Her blues is from the gut. The pop sounds are catchy and mature."
        B00002066I,ah,15.99,A2KLYVAS0MIBMQ,Stephen McClaning,0/0,5.0,1332288000,Great CD,"My lovely Pat has one of the GREAT voices of her generation. I have listened to this CD for YEARS and I still LOVE IT. When I'm in a good mood it makes me feel better. A bad mood just evaporates like sugar in the rain. This CD just oozes LIFE. Vocals are jusat STUUNNING and lyrics just kill. One of life's hidden gems. This is a desert isle CD in my book. Why she never made it big is just beyond me. Everytime I play this, no matter black, white, young, old, male, female EVERYBODY says one thing ""Who was that singing ?"""
B000058A81,Chrono Cross,unknown,A18C9SNLZWVBIE,A reader,1/1,5.0,1096934400,First album I've bought since Napster,"We've come a long way since the days of Ninetendo synthesized music! I say without exaggeration that the Chrono Cross Original Soundtrack is probably some of the best instrumental music I've ever heard. Yasunori Mitsuda incorporates so many instruments and musical styles to this collection, it's a real credit to his talent. Guitars, violins, cellos and the piano are just a few of the instruments at play here. Although they differ greatly in musical style, I have to draw an analogy between Mitsuda's music here to the songs of the Grateful Dead"
```

It indexes the first two line but after that it shows an error:

```
C:\muj\Downloads\solr-7.1.0\example\exampledocs>java -Dc=newamz -Dtype=application/csv -jar post.jar amazon.csv
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/newamz/update using content-type application/csv...
POSTing file amazon.csv to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/newamz/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":297},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=10e1a7ce-f308-471f-980d-202a6454d9ab] Error adding field 'product_price'='unknown' msg=For input string: \"unknown\"",
    "code":400}}
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/newamz/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/newamz/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.766
```

The solr is working in schemaless mode.
Note:The  actual csv file size is very large.

These are fields which I can find in the manage schema file:

```
<copyField source="review_userId" dest="review_userId_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="review_profileName" dest="review_profileName_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="product_productId" dest="product_productId_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="review_text" dest="review_text_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="review_helpfulness" dest="review_helpfulness_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="review_summary" dest="review_summary_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="prod
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a field that is apparently numeric, then suddenly you're trying to index a string value into that field. Solr complains about being unable to convert that string to a number (i.e. "unknown" is not a valid number: `'product_price'='unknown'`).

Since you're running in schemaless mode, the first format for the field determines its type. If you want to avoid this, define an explicit schema with the datatypes allowed for the field.

Comment: You've only pasted the copyField instructions and the text is cut half way through.